# SVM function in R

Tags: r, svm, libsvm

I am using R for classification problem. Does svm function in R support only binary classfication or supports multi class classification as welll?

Comment: Because someone there also might be able to help

Answer (score 3):

svm (in package e1071) supports multi class classification using the ‘one-against-one’-approach. Same with ksvm (in kernlab).

Comment: You mean for each class it use binary classification. Means I can use it to classsify my data into 3 classes

Comment: Yes, as long as it detects more that 2 classes in your dependent variable, it applies the ‘one-against-one’-approach automatically

Comment: I am basically trying to predict buy-sell-hold signals based on the trained neural net. I a using radial basis function, my C varies from 1-100 and gamma varies between 0.00001 - 1 but the problem is trained neural net does not predict precisely on testing dataset. Could you help me what possibly could be the reason for this problem?

Comment: @user395882 You follow-up question is beyond the scope of your original question, and we try to limit ourselves to one question per post here. Unless it is specifically about code, it would also be off-topic here. You might try either stats.stackexchange.com or quant.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Set upper limit for gamma upto 5000 and increase lower limit to 0.005.

Answer (score 0):

The e1071 R package supports multi class classification using a "one-against-one-method".

Here are the classifications in this package:

- v-classication: this model allows for more control over the number of support vectors (see Scholkopf et al., 2000) by specifying an additional parameter which approximates the fraction of support vectors;
- One-class-classication: this model tries to find the support of a distribution and thus allows for outlier/novelty detection;
- Multi-class classication: basically, SVMs can only solve binary classication problems. To allow for multi-class classication, libsvm uses the one-against-one technique by fitting all binary subclassiers and finding the correct class by a voting mechanism;
- e-regression: here, the data points lie in between the two borders of the margin which is maximized under suitable conditions to avoid outlier inclusion;

Check https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/e1071/vignettes/svmdoc.pdf